# Print axMapControl contents with preview

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine, printing

I have a map with many feature layers on top of it. I would like to be able to print the map and feature layers either scaling it to fit a certain page size or printing it to actual scale thus creating a mosaic of printed pages.
Ideally I would like to preview the results before sending them to printer and I am having two major issues doing so.

What I did so far is get the map onto a axPageLayoutControl so that I can add artifacts about which part of the mosaic each page is, scalebars, titles etc. Although getting the axMapControl.ActiveView.FocusMap which appears as landscape, in the PageLayout (orientation set to landscape) the map appears in portait (actually showing a slightly different extend). Changing the pageLayout.page.orientation has no effect on the map. Also I tried drawing all the features from the axMapControl onto the pageLayout but the spread in a much bigger area than the map itself, but this time in landscape orientation.

Another problem is that I don't know how to preview the mosaic pages after setting the esriPageToPrinterMapping.esriPageMappingTile value to the axPageLayoutControl.Page.PageToPrinterMapping property as this does change the number of pages axPageLayoutControl.get_PrinterPageCount() to more than 1, but has no effect on the pageLayout or the printout itself.

Comment: The asker of this question (it actually looks like two questions) has not been seen on the site for 9 months.  Is it still of interest to anyone?  If not, I propose that it be closed so that we can "focus" on the other 5,000 Unanswered Questions.

Comment: Reading the site without being logged in does not mean I am not visiting. The question is still valid, it has not been answered and it can definitely be reproduced, but I guess not many people implement printing in their application. Feel free to close the question as I have implemented printing without using ESRI.

Comment: Thanks for understanding - some of the Close reasons do not match all scenarios to which they are applied closely.  If you are keen to keep it alive, or to reactivate it at some time in the future, perhaps you can revise it to try and attract more attention.  Re-testing at 10.2, if you have not already, and updating its version tag accordingly may also act as a good trigger.